# Applying authentication in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, authentication

I am trying to apply basic authentication in GeoServer but somehow it is not reflecting while consuming the WMS service through OpenLayers.

I am accessing it thorough below urls:

- http://admin:geoserver@localhost:8080/geoserver/localhost/wms?.. // psw as plain text (GetMap)
- http://admin:Z2Vvc2VydmVy@localhost:8080/geoserver/localhost/wms?.. // psw as base64 encrypted. (GetMap)
- http://admin:Z2Vvc2VydmVy@localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities //Check for capabilities

Either way it is not working. Below are the screen shots from GeoServer :

Filter Chain :
[image]

default chain config (with basic authentication as well)

[image]

I created a Child role and created a child user with this role, Also I created service access rule as below

[image]

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is not working? no access? no password required?

Comment: I tried with the 3 url's , One with capability gives message : Problem accessing /geoserver/wms. Other 2 calls form openlayers does not render any layer.

Comment: Can you assist me on how to send credentials to GeoServer request, Also once the credentials are provided in popup on browser the WMS url does not ask for the credential second time until I close the browser and run the url again.

Answer (score 0):

Acording [Geoserver-docs Layer security](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/layer.html#security-layer), challenge or mixed mode help you to access private data, the Geoserver forces most clients to show an authentication dialog which mean you can use basic auth. Otherwise you will receive a HTTP 401 code or HTTP 404 code if mode is hide.

Security->Data->MIXED
[image]